# Second page for PDFContentByte

Tags: itext

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple, but since I've been breaking my head on this for a while, I'm just going to ask.

I'm using JavaScript to access the iText (Java) library to take a filable PDF and serve it up via a browser. The process has worked for my first one, and now I'm doing one where the original fillable PDF has 2 pages. I've been trying to get the second page for a while now. I'm using the PdfContentByte to get it to the browser, and it works except I can't seem to get the PdfContentByte to have a second page. My relevant code is below. When I add the second template (page2) they way I do, it moves what I'm writing, but I'm still just getting one (US letter) page.

This may not be the most efficient code, but like I said, I've been trying a few things on this. If someone has a pointer, I would be very grateful.

```
var cb:com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte = writer.getDirectContent();    
var cb2:com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte = writer.getDirectContent();    
var reader2:com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader(os.toByteArray());    
var page:com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage = writer.getImportedPage(reader2, 1); 

cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);  //this works as expected 

var page2:com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage = writer.getImportedPage(reader2, 2); 

// this will add, and with the 100 do an offset, but the
// "physical size" of the paper is the same 
cb2.addTemplate(page2, 0, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of iText in Action, 2nd edition, especially at subsection 6.4.1: Concatenating and splitting PDF documents.

Listing 6.22, [ConcatenateStamp.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=128), shows you how you should create a PDF from copies of pages of multiple other PDFs; the sample actually additionally adds a new "Page X of Y" footer which you may keep or remove from the sample.

Comment: That helped, thank you mkl. I'm adding a new page the the document, then placing the second page at a -2 position. That works for my 2 pages, but I'll have to come up with something else for if I need a third.